# pydev enable folding on big files

Tags: eclipse, pydev, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-luna

After recently re-installing pydev (3rd party eclipse plugin), I was surprised to find that folding doesn't work for some large files (25k+ lines). I used another (recent) version of pydev previously and folding worked fine. After quite some wondering/googling/fumbling through menus I stumbled upon :

> [Pydev Changelog](http://pydev.org/history_pydev.html):
>   Code folding marks won't be shown on really large files for performance reasons

The files I'm working with *did have folds* in a 2.x release I had at that time, but the changelog states they were disabled under version 1.5.7. I am absolutely sure they worked in a more recent version. Could be a conflict with another plugin ?

The real question is ***how do I force the folding feature to be enabled on big files*** (exactly where it is needed most that is) ?
An answer in the form of a patch - or just an indication of where in pydev code can this be disabled will be enough - if it is not possible via the GUI

Eclipse Kepler - up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2014.01.03 17.27**: after so much time being unable to touch the thing I decided to install the latest pydev (3.2.0.201312292215). Lo and behold the folding markers are back on my 30000 lines file. I close this for now.

<sub>Still interested in an answer in my original question - if some developer pops in and clarifies the situation I would accept it as an answer</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It appears that eclipse automatically disables live parsing in the editors if files are larger than a configurable limit. If you click on Window -> Preferences and search for "Scalability" you will find an option to set this file size limit or you can simply deselect the option to disable live parsing (which includes folding). This solution is not specific to pydev but should do the trick.

Comment: I left this bugmass that is pydev behind and went for PyCharm which is perfectly fine. Once I reinstall it (will do at some point soonish) I will check and let you know !

Comment: `Window -> Preferences and search for "Scalability"` no such option - eclipse Luna

Comment: I am using Eclipse Helios and used the above solution for working with C files. The Scalability settings was under the Editor settings. I guess the same doesn't apply for pydev..

Comment: Ηλιος ?!¨?!?!?! May I ask why not the latest ? I use eclipse for Java EE - apparently scalability is not a vanilla setting (I do not have PyDev installed)